# How should I store docker credentials?

Tags: security, docker, authentication

First off I want to say I have very limited knowledge when it comes to security and authentication.

I have an app that pulls and runs containers from the docker store. This is a private repo so I need to pass the username and password so the user can pull. On mac the login credentials get stored in the keychain and the user can open their keychain and read the password in plain text. How do I prevent this so users can't see my credentials?

The credentials are currently stored in plain text in a json. I know this is not good practice but even if it was encrypted (as far as I'm concerned) it would have to be decrypted before logging in and it gets stored in the keychain after it logs in so the keychain would still store my credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at [Docker secrets](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/)

> In terms of Docker Swarm services, a secret is a blob of data, such as
>   a password, SSH private key, SSL certificate, or another piece of data
>   that should not be transmitted over a network or stored unencrypted in
>   a Dockerfile or in your application’s source code. In Docker 1.13 and
>   higher, you can use Docker secrets to centrally manage this data and
>   securely transmit it to only those containers that need access to it.
>   Secrets are encrypted during transit and at rest in a Docker swarm. A
>   given secret is only accessible to those services which have been
>   granted explicit access to it, and only while those service tasks are
>   running.
>
> Docker secrets are only available to swarm services, not to standalone
>   containers. To use this feature, consider adapting your container to
>   run as a service. Stateful containers can typically run with a scale
>   of 1 without changing the container code.